# AutoIt cannot close IE after click on link

Tags: autoit

I want to load a website and click on one of its links, but after clicking on the link, _IEQuit not worked.
What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <IE.au3>

Call ("load_web")


Func load_web()
    Global $oIE = _IECreate ("http://www.hqweb.ir")
    Local $link = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "link")
    _IEAction($link, "click")
    _IEQuit($oIE)
EndFunc
```

Comment: Hello. This code seems to be working for me. It opens the webpage, clicks a link, then closes the browser.

Comment: @TimothyBomer what if the link opens in a new window?

Comment: @whsanshirzadi I apologize, what do you mean? The code you posted above opens a new window. Are you trying to open it in a new tab of an already open window?

Comment: @TimothyBomer thanks for your reply man, my link in my website opens in a new tab (target=_blank), So when I want to close, first tab will be closed, How to close to second tab?

Comment: Is this your whole code? If not, could you edit the question to include the rest so I can see what you're needing? Also, just a note... You don't need to call a function using the Call() function. You can simply use the function name with the trailing paranthesis. For example, Call ("load_web") can be reduced to simply load_web().